# async sqlConnection exceptions

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to write an async connection to my SQL server but I hit a wall with catching exceptions. MSDN was not very helpful about it.
My first approach was:

```
async Task dbConnAsync(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync(); //Here i get InvalidOperationException
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private async void ReadDB()
    {
            try
            {
                Task theTask = dbConnAsync(conn);
                await theTask;                  
            }.....
    }
```

And the second one:

```
private async void dbConnection()
    {
            try
            {
                 await conn.OpenAsync();               
            }.....
    }
```

And after many other attempts I decided to consult the experts, so How do I catch exceptions when the program can't connect to server.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does the code do that you don't want?

Comment: i can't catch exception InvalidOperationException "The connection was not closed the connection's current state is connecting" it happens when sqls server is shoutdown.

Comment: Are you sure you're not catching it? Your code should work fine. Maybe you have first chance exception dialog on in VS? Try to run your code without debugging.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that it's my bad day in debug option i enable a while back to trow all exception not just undhandeled -_-'. Last question how to stop my task after first exception now i get exception and every timeout period.

Comment: I see that you're engaged in discussion under this question. Did you evaluate my answer yet? I generally like to know if it helped (or if it didn't, why).

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that the connection is already in the process of opening. Probably you called `conn.OpenAsync` previously without waiting for it to complete. Probably you are missing an `await`.

So the fix is not to catch the exception but to eliminate the underlying cause. Catching is just treating the symptom.